Recursor in system T of Gödel and reduction rules
When studying system T (lets say from Lectures on the Curry-Howard isomorphism, but I have studied from many sources) of Gödel I can see that the recursor follows the reduction rules:
$$R_{\sigma}MN0\Rightarrow N$$
$$R_{\sigma}MN(sP)\Rightarrow MP(R_{\sigma}MNP)$$
for terms of appropriate type. Could someone explain to me how is $R_{\sigma}MNP$ reduced afterwards? I get confused because I think that $P$ could be a term that doesn't start with an $s$, but is neither $0$ (e.g. variable x). So I don't see the appropriate reduction rule. Does this mean that it stays as it is $R_{\sigma}MNx$?

Yes, if nothing more is given about $P$, you cannot reduce it further. And yes $P$ does not have to be a term starting with $s$ or beeing $0$. It is even possible that $P$ is something like "$sss\dots$" (ongoing forever) and you have an infinite reduction chain.
If, however, your terms are total, meaning simply that $P$ has the form $s...s0$, then the reduction terminates.
